# Orbeon forms - setting value of autocomplete field and triggering validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, orbeon

I have scenario, where the Orbeon Form is prepopulated from the back-end by some values that the user has entered on the previous (non-Orbeon) page. The fields that are being prepopulated are actually **autocomplete** field (*created with Form Builder*).

*Autocomplete suggestions* for each of those fields are provided by my back-end controller. I have made a workaround to allow the user to keep the data that he has input even if it doesn't exist in the original itemset. The only exception is **postal code**, where another **external validation**  takes place and displays the error in case the user has entered something which doesn't match back-end itemset.

This external validation is implemented via service which is called on change of postal code field, and that service populates one additional **hidden** field (e.g. *postalCodeValidationResult*) with value *true/false* and I'm actually checking if the postal code entered is valid or not based on this *true/false* value *postalCodeValidationResult* field.

> E.g. User enters postal code, city and street on Page A, and after he
>   gets to Page B, those values have to be pre-populated in matching
>   fields on Orbeon Form on Page B. Since postal code needs to be a real
>   one, I need to trigger somehow the external validation of that postal code
>   field (i.e. call the external service for validation).

The problem I am facing is when user enters wrong postal code on Page A, then I populate it on Page B, and should somehow trigger validation when the form loads. But, I cannot succeed in triggering that validation. I assume that I would have to trigger an **xforms-value-changed** event or something similar, but this doesn't seem to work, or I am missing something. I tried:

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.dispatchEvent(
            {
                targetId:  'address-postal-code-control',
                eventName: 'xforms-value-changed'
            }
        );
```

and also this:

```
var control = ORBEON.jQuery('*[id $= "address-postal-code-control"]');
ORBEON.xforms.Document.dispatchEvent(
            {
                targetId:  control.attr('id'),
                eventName: 'xforms-value-changed'
            }
        );
```

But no success. While testing, I tried also to manually change the value from JavaScript (instead of prepopulating) but even this wouldn't work - is it because it's not regular input field, but autocomplete field?

```
ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue(control.attr('id'), "69121");
```

Does anybody have an idea of how this could be achieved? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

---

*Additional info (Autocomplete definition)*

```
<fr:autocomplete xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"" xmlns:xxbl=""http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"" 
    id=""address-postal-code-control"" labelref=""@label""
    resource=""$config-gev.autosuggest.url.address/autosuggest/zurs?facet=postalCode&amp;postalCode={$fr-search-value}"" 
    bind=""address-postal-code-bind""
    class=""personal-details-input address-postal-code"">
          <xf:label ref=""$form-resources/address-postal-code/label""/>
          <xf:hint ref=""$form-resources/address-postal-code/hint""/>
          <xf:alert ref=""$form-resources/address-postal-code/alert[1]""  validation=""validation-68-validation""/>
          <xf:itemset ref=""/suggestions/suggestion"">
                <xf:label ref=""result""/>
                <xf:value ref=""result""/>
           </xf:itemset>
</fr:autocomplete>
```

*Additional info (Validation action)*

```
<xf:action id=""validatePostalCode-regular-binding"">

            <xf:action ev:event=""xforms-value-changed"" ev:observer=""address-postal-code-control"" if=""true()"">
                <xf:send submission=""validatePostalCode-submission""/>
            </xf:action>

            <xf:action ev:event=""xforms-submit"" ev:observer=""validatePostalCode-submission"">

                <xf:var name=""request-instance-name"" value=""'validatePostalCode-instance'"" as=""xs:string""/>

                <xf:insert ref=""instance('fr-service-request-instance')"" origin=""saxon:parse(instance($request-instance-name))""/> 
                <xf:action context=""instance('fr-service-request-instance')"">
                    <xf:action class=""fr-set-service-value-action"">
                        <xf:var name=""control-name"" value=""'address-postal-code'""/>
                        <xf:var name=""path"" value=""/request/postalCode""/>
                    </xf:action>
                    <!-- Setvalue actions will be here -->
                </xf:action>
            </xf:action>

            <xf:action ev:event=""xforms-submit-done"" ev:observer=""validatePostalCode-submission"" context=""instance('fr-service-response-instance')"">
                <xf:action class=""fr-set-control-value-action"">
                    <xf:var name=""control-name"" value=""'postalCodeValidationResult-regular'""/>
                    <xf:var name=""control-value"" value=""/result/valid""/>
                </xf:action>  
            </xf:action>
</xf:action>
```

Comment: If it was an input field, the right way to set its value from JavaScript would be to use `ORBEON.xforms.Document.setValue()`. But this doesn't work with the autocomplete. Should it? It isn't clear to me, as what you're setting isn't the value of the control, but its label. If you're doing this from XForms, the proper way to do it is by [dispatching the `fr-set-label` event](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/autocomplete.html#setting-by-label). But there isn't really an equivalent for this in JavaScript.

Comment: Now however, why do you need to set the value of this field from JavaScript? Or do you just need to trigger a value change? I haven't followed that part of your description.

Comment: And for future reference, here is [the source of a form to test setting the value of an autocomplete from JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/avernet/f5a967ff254d60b99fe525a06e80c5c6).